# Resteasy InMemoryClientEngine where is it?

Tags: resteasy

In the Resteasy documentation (4.3.1.Final) I found indication about InMemoryClientEngine as client engine.

I didn't find the class in the resteasy-client jar.
Could someone indicate in which jar the class is included?

What's the maven definition I should use?

Answer (score 0):

The `InMemoryClientEngine` is only used for some testing and is not meant to be used for general purposes. I've filed an [issues](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/RESTEASY-3301) to remove the reference from the documentation.

It looks like the `InMemoryClientEngine` was removed in [3.1](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/RESTEASY-1363).